# Spark on YARN resource manager: Relation between YARN Containers and Spark Executors

Tags: apache-spark, containers, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, executor

I'm new to Spark on YARN and don't understand the relation between the YARN `Containers` and the Spark `Executors`. I tried out the following configuration, based on the results of the `yarn-utils.py` script, that can be used to find optimal cluster configuration.

The Hadoop cluster (HDP 2.4) I'm working on:

- 1 Master Node:

  - CPU: 2 CPUs with 6 cores each = 12 cores
  - RAM: 64 GB
  - SSD: 2 x 512 GB
- 5 Slave Nodes:

  - CPU: 2 CPUs with 6 cores each = 12 cores
  - RAM: 64 GB
  - HDD: 4 x 3 TB = 12 TB
- HBase is installed (this is one of the parameters for the script below)

So I ran `python yarn-utils.py -c 12 -m 64 -d 4 -k True` (c=cores, m=memory, d=hdds, k=hbase-installed) and got the following result:

```
 Using cores=12 memory=64GB disks=4 hbase=True
 Profile: cores=12 memory=49152MB reserved=16GB usableMem=48GB disks=4
 Num Container=8
 Container Ram=6144MB
 Used Ram=48GB
 Unused Ram=16GB
 yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=6144
 yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=49152
 yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=49152
 mapreduce.map.memory.mb=6144
 mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4915m
 mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=6144
 mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx4915m
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=6144
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts=-Xmx4915m
 mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=2457
```

These settings I made via the Ambari interface and restarted the cluster. The values also match roughly what I calculated manually before.

I have now problems

- to find the optimal settings for my `spark-submit` script

  - parameters `--num-executors`, `--executor-cores` & `--executor-memory`.
- to get the relation between the YARN container and the Spark executors
- to understand the hardware information in my Spark History UI (less memory shown as I set (when calculated to overall memory by multiplying with worker node amount))
- to understand the concept of the `vcores` in YARN, here I couldn't find any useful examples yet

However, I found this post [What is a container in YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365218/what-is-a-container-in-yarn) , but this didn't really help as it doesn't describe the relation to the executors.

Can someone help to solve one or more of the questions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I will report my insights here step by step:

- First important thing is this fact (Source: [this Cloudera documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html)):

  > When running Spark on YARN, each Spark executor runs as a YARN container. [...]
- This means the number of containers will always be the same as the executors created by a Spark application e.g. via `--num-executors` parameter in spark-submit.
- Set by the `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` every container always allocates at least this amount of memory. This means if parameter `--executor-memory` is set to e.g. only `1g` but `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` is e.g. `6g`, the container is much bigger than needed by the Spark application.
- The other way round, if the parameter `--executor-memory` is set to somthing higher than the `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` value, e.g. `12g`, the Container will allocate more memory dynamically, but **only** if the requested amount of memory is smaller or equal to `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` value.
- The value of `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` determines, how much memory can be allocated in sum by **all containers of one host**!

**=>** So setting `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` allows you to run smaller containers e.g. for smaller executors (**else it would be waste of memory**).

**=>** Setting `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` to the maximum value (e.g. equal to `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`) allows you to define bigger executors (more memory is allocated if needed, e.g. by `--executor-memory` parameter).

Comment: do we have to set/alter `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` on each cluster node?

Answer (score 0):

When running Spark on YARN, each Spark executor runs as a YARN container.
Where MapReduce schedules a container and starts a JVM for each task, Spark hosts multiple tasks within the same container. This approach enables several orders of magnitude faster task startup time.

In YARN, each application instance has an ApplicationMaster process, which is the first container started for that application. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzYYh.png)